# How to run a new thread process?

Tags: python, linux

would you help me find a way run the new process separately(say in background) without control by the main daemon so as the main function code can keep walk. despite of the new generated process.
Means script can reach "complete" in file 1 instead of waiting the func1 to done.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import os,time

def func1():
    while True:
        print('func1: starting')
        os.system("echo catch >> 1")
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.start()
  p1.join()
  os.system("echo complete >> 1")
```

Comment: `p1.join()`waits for end of process so use it at the end of your script and run your code between `p1.start()` and `p1.join()`

Comment: it is not clear whether you want a thread or a process. There are some important distinctions between them

Comment: @furas Thank you for your comment ! it works now.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should change the main script like this :

```
  p1.start()
  p1 = Process(target=func1)
  p1.join()
  os.system("echo complete >> 1")
```